# Hacker Earth's Monk and Rotation Time limit exceeded

Tags: algorithm, go

I am trying to solve the following question from Hacker Earth which is Monk and Rotation
Please refer the link: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/ .
It's a beginner level problem which I managed to solve but unfortunately I am facing *Time limit exceeded* issue for *Input #5*

I have tried to optimize the solution. I think I managed to do so up to some extent wrt my crude solution in the beginning but sadly that's not enough.

I suspect the flaw lies with how I handle the input and it could be the bottleneck.

It may also have to do with how I am handling slices but I don't see a better way than that. Before optimization I was certain that slices were the culprit.

Edit:
I was not aware the question is not accessible without login, here is some brief explaination.

> Input:
>
> The first line will consists of one integer T denoting the number of
> test cases. For each test case:
>
> 1. The first line consists of two
>    integers N and K, N being the number of elements in the array and K
>    denotes the number of steps of rotation.
> 2. The next line consists of
>    N space separated integers , denoting the elements of the array A.
>
> Output:
> Print the required array.
>
> Constraints:
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 20
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
> 0 ≤ K ≤ 10^6
> 0 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10^6
>
> Sample Input:
> 1
> 5 2
> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> Sample Output:
> 4 5 1 2 3

**Explanation**

*Here T is 1, which means one test case.
N = 5 denoting the number of elements in the array and K = 2, denoting the number of steps of rotations.

The initial array is 1,2,3,4,5:

In first rotation, 5 will come in the first position and all other elements will move to one position ahead from their current position. Now, the resultant array will be 5,1,2,3,4.

In second rotation, 4 will come in the first position and all other elements will move to one position ahead from their current position. Now, the resultant array will be 4,5,1,2,3*

> Time Limit: 1.0 sec(s) for each input file (2x for Golang)
> Memory Limit: 256 MB
> Source Limit: 1024 KB.

[Input #5](https://he-s3.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/codemonk-arrays-strings-2/problems/f9ee428ab15c11ea.txt.clean.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=bcf93032c6965e60e3ff28d01371aec07fb21f6d33a041401b27883bfef27b96&X-Amz-Date=20220121T034519Z&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA6I2ISGOYH7WWS3G5%2F20220121%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var testCases int
    var arrSize, rotation int
    fmt.Scanln(&testCases)

    for i := 0; i < testCases; i++ {
        fmt.Scanln(&arrSize, &rotation)
        arr := make([]int, arrSize)
        for i := range arr {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &arr[i])
        }

        rotation = rotation % arrSize

        for i := arrSize - rotation; i < arrSize; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", arr[i])
        }
        for i := 0; i < arrSize-rotation; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", arr[i])
        }
        fmt.Print("\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the description of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you give a problem description? You can only see the link if you register.

Comment: in addition, even the link you provided isn't of a specific problem and requires signup if you want to look further.

Comment: Can `rotation` be negative?

Comment: I have updated the question with detailed explanation about the problem statement. @Damien, rotation can't be negative, but can be greater than length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your solution seems to be O(n), so I would say that your solution is "correct". You could probably optimize by not constructing an array and reading number after number. Just read the whole line. Find the index where to split the string and print the two substrings in reverse order.